# How to check a DB table in Ionic

Tags: android, typescript, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I recently had to update my Ionic application to include the acquisition of a new piece of data.
Within my app, it's possible to store data locally for future use, but I encountered an issue.
The new data couldn't be saved on the device because the table I was using didn't has a column for the new data.
Ultimately, the problem was that the table had been stored in the device cache and wasn't getting updated.

To resolve the issue, I simply had to clear the cache, but I can't have users of the app doing this manually.
What I want to ask is how I can check the details of the table to know if it has updated?
And if it hasn't updated, how do I clear the user's cache or force a table update?

This is the code I use to generate the table:

```
createDatabase() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'clockings.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.database = db;
        db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,user_id INTEGER(10),clocking_date_time DATETIME, client_id INTEGER (10),latitude FLOAT(10), longitude FLOAT(10), type BOOLEAN, note VARCHAR (191), trip_time VARCHAR (50))', [])
          .then((data) => console.log('New table clocking created', data))
          .catch(e => console.log(e));
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```